# Objective-C iPhone - UIImagePickerController error

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm doing something with UIImagePickerController.

It works fine and the Picture browser does open, however, I get this message.
"Failed to save the videos metadata to the filesystem. Maybe the information did not conform to a plist."

What could be causing that? That is caused by this line
[self presentModalViewController:self.imgPicker animated:YES]; which is activated on a button click

Snippets of the code that I have below.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    self.imgPicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    self.imgPicker.allowsImageEditing = YES;
    self.imgPicker.delegate = self;  
}

- (IBAction)grabImage {
    [self presentModalViewController:self.imgPicker animated:YES];
}
```

Thanks,
Tee

Comment: Use the code formatting options of stackoverflow. That makes things much more readable.

Answer (score 2):

Many people have seen that error.  It appears to not actually have any negative impact on your app, however.  So don't worry about and hope Apple fixes it in the next SDK.

Here's a thread on the Apple dev forums about it (Apple iPhone developer account required)
https://devforums.apple.com/message/144567#144567

No solutions have turned up to my knowledge.